# Wordpress тема грузит главную страницу при визуальном изменении

Tags: php, wordpress

Делая тему под wordpress, столкнулся с проблемой! Я добавил в тему возможность редактировать страницу с бокового меню настройки темы, а именно:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вот при изменении каких либо параметров, вместо того что бы страница обновлялась и применялись изменения, система грузит главную страницу! При этом если войти снова на редактируемую страницу, изменения будут применены..
Вопрос: почему оно грузит главную страницу, при применении изменений, а не обновляет текущую (редактируемую)?

```
add_action( 'customize_register', 'lwp_about_customize' );



function lwp_about_customize($wp_customize) {
    $wp_customize->add_section('lwp-about-section', array(
        'title' => 'About Page'
    ));

    $wp_customize->add_setting('lwp-about-title', array(
        'default' => ''
    ));

    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Control($wp_customize, 'lwp-about-page-control', array(
        'label' => 'Title',
        'section' => 'lwp-about-section',
        'settings' => 'lwp-about-title'
    )));

    $wp_customize->add_setting('lwp-about-text', array(
        'default' => ''
    ));

    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Control($wp_customize, 'lwp-about-text-control', array(
        'label' => 'Text',
        'section' => 'lwp-about-section',
        'settings' => 'lwp-about-text',
        'type' => 'textarea'
    )));
}

<h2><?php echo get_theme_mod('lwp-about-title'); ?></h2>
<p><?php echo wpautop( get_theme_mod('lwp-about-text')); ?></p><br>
```

Comment: Потому что неправильно сделал. Ваш КЭП. Документация тут https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/customize-api/

Comment: добавил код. что не так?

Comment: Я совсем немного разбирался с кастойзером, но что-то мне подсказывает, что в коде не хватает указания на пациента. Ака редактируемой страницы.